# how to make the expand slide always under a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I make the `outside` div always underneath the current `item` div. the code works fine but if it has two lines, like the image below.

The outside div would be on the top if I click `box6` or `box7`. If there is a way I could make `outside` div change the position dynamically?

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" data-content="1">1
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-content="2">2
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-content="3">3
    </div>
       <div class="outside">
       </div>
</div>



.outside {
    background:yellow;
    background: #222222;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:80px;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

**Sample online http://jsfiddle.net/nm3Y4/**

Thanks a lot for the answers and your time. I think I didn't make it clear, so what I wanted to achieve is that, if you click box1, should looks like  the image below

[image]

and when click on box6 or box7 should show like below
[image]

so which means that `outside` below current `item` div

Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the value of `top` property of the absolutely positioned `.outside` element according to the *height* of the `.item` box and the *top offset* of the current clicked item:

```
$('.item').click(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var contentNumber = $this.data("content");

    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass("active");

    $('.content').hide();
    $('.content'+contentNumber).show();
    $('.outside')
        .css('top', $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 'px')
        .slideDown();     
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/nm3Y4/8/)**.

As a **side-note**: It's better to position the `.outside` element relative to the `.container` rather than the initial containing block.

```css
.container {
     /* Create a containing block for the absolutely positioned elements */
    position: relative;
}
```

Also `float: left;` declaration is redundant for the `.outside` as it's positioned absolutely.

---

As per your update, you could `relative` positioning and add `top` property in order to position the *items* (which their *top offset* is higher than the current clicked *item*) when the **click event** is triggered:

```css
.item {
    /* other styles here... */
    float:left;
    position: relative; /* Position the items relatively */
}
```

```javascript
$('.item').click(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // ...
    $('.item').filter(function() {
        return $(this).offset().top > $this.offset().top;
    }).css('top', $('.outside').height() + 'px');
    // ...   
});
```

Then reset their position when the `.outside` is closed:

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $('.item').css('top', '0'); // reset the top property/value
    $('.outside').slideUp();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/nm3Y4/12/)**.

Comment: it is overlapping the item div,while my answer doesn't

Comment: @SajadLfc I think the OP wants to position the `.outside` relative to the current clicked item not generally below the container box.

Comment: If so, s/he could just remove the `absolute: position` from the `.outside` and add `clear: both;` to that in order to clear the float as: **http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/nm3Y4/10/**

Comment: unfortunately, once you click on first line items, there's no way to see any on second line if any ... unless you close the box. this is obvious to us, but to lambda web user ? :) (it is also the point of my answer with both example linked :) )

Comment: @GCyrillus That's right, I'm just answering what the OP wants. However     my second last comment would be helpful in that case.

Comment: @HashemQolami , it's fine to me :)

Comment: @SajadLfc , relative puts it back in the flow and will reorder whatever stands behind it , it could be messy and breaking original layout :)

Comment: @HashemQolami, thanks for your answer, just checked the demo found that, the expanded slide overlaps the 2nd line - `item` divs

Answer (score 1):

remove `position:absolute`  and `top:80px` and add  `clear:both;`

```
.outside {
    background:yellow;
    background: #222222;
    clear:both;
    display: none;


    width:100%;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nm3Y4/11/)

Comment: Sajad, I think in this case there's no need to use `top` property as the element is positioned in its place in the flow. Also consider [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423556/how-to-make-the-expand-slide-always-under-a-div/22423635#comment34097700_22423635) to clea the float of the items.

Comment: @HashemQolami:considered..!!

Comment: +1 Good job. However `position: relative;` is redundant here :)

Comment: @HashemQolami:forgot to remove it..!! but already removed from demo,now removed from both answer and demo..!! thankYou for the valuable suggestion..!!

Comment: you could use only CSS since your box has an height http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/cJqrE

Answer (score 1):

*since question is updated, this answer doesnt fit the need, 
i leave it here just because it shows behavior of absolute element if no coordonates are given ...*

you could reset white-space and not float the divs to keep them on 1 line.
http://jsfiddle.net/nm3Y4/7/

```
.slider {
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 580px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider li {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.item {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
    margin:10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.content {
    display:none;
}
.active {
    background:blue;
}
.outside {
    background:yellow;
    background: #222222;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:80px;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    height: 300px;
}
.close {
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.container {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.outside {
    white-space:normal;
}
```

**or do not let your box float, inline-block is just fine,  and remove the top coordonates, see :** http://jsfiddle.net/nm3Y4/9/